# Как получить макс высоту с padding?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет есть такая структура

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Надо получить мак. высоту для каждого элемента wrapper( Для одного wrapper'a вычитывается max высота у item'ов) Т.е самая большая высота которая есть у одного из них? Однако классы повторяются и интересно как сделать что бы было на каждый wrapper разная макс

Comment: А для чего высчитывать max-height?

Comment: +1 К вопросу выше,все еще зависит от стилей

Comment: Немного не понятно, вы хотите получить высоту каждого `wrapper`?

Answer (score 2):

ну если я правильно понял, что ты хочешь

```
$('.wrapper').each(function(i, el){
  console.log($(el).outerHeight())
})
```

```js
$('.wrapper').each(function(i, el) {
  console.log($(el).outerHeight())
})
```

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis eligendi vitae consequatur iste atque tenetur similique ratione veniam obcaecati, nostrum cum, in at. Repellat libero similique asperiores quo, est optio, doloribus doloremque illo
      unde sapiente fugiat distinctio eligendi quae quos nesciunt, vitae eveniet! Est molestias eaque facere facilis, nisi commodi qui odio vero eligendi ipsum repudiandae iste beatae eius amet obcaecati optio nemo adipisci. Vel dolor, earum aperiam magni
      voluptatibus totam!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque mollitia, iste quae enim magnam nesciunt reiciendis, nam id quod fugit in officia modi veniam odit.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae quibusdam vero aperiam.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, voluptatem.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae modi sequi, incidunt perspiciatis molestiae consectetur voluptatem dolorum?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam, omnis corrupti suscipit fugit error, cupiditate excepturi maxime, veritatis hic iste voluptates tenetur repudiandae beatae accusamus aliquam debitis temporibus voluptate eum incidunt
      explicabo optio ratione. Cupiditate libero error reiciendis architecto ipsa repudiandae, repellat, incidunt aut debitis nemo aliquid sed dolore excepturi!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas, molestiae.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ullam, animi. Incidunt!</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ipsam eveniet laborum magni natus doloribus itaque nostrum corporis? Quidem delectus itaque aliquid voluptates veniam minima ratione numquam molestiae tenetur ipsa.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Unde sapiente cum cupiditate eligendi repudiandae illum? Repellat omnis fugit minus ab debitis qui vero unde numquam.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem, natus.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odit, fuga.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var wrapper = $( ".wrapper" );
var data = [];

$.each( wrapper, function( key ) {
  data.push($(wrapper[key]).innerHeight())
});

console.log(data)
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
}
.item {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```